# HtmlUnit error will not get second page after javascript?

Tags: htmlunit

Somebody please explain why am getting null pointer exception

```
HtmlPage page = null;
boolean savePagesLocally = false;
String url = "http://example.com";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
try
{
    page = webClient.getPage( url );

    HtmlRadioButtonInput radioButton2 = (HtmlRadioButtonInput) page.getElementById("ctl00_phContent_ucUnifiedSearch_rdoIndvl");
    radioButton2.click();

    HtmlTextInput textField3 = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("ctl00_phContent_ucUnifiedSearch_txtIndvl");
    textField3.setValueAttribute("1061726"); // null pointer occurs here!
```

Comment: Can you post the html code? And is this java code?

Comment: It is java generated by htmlscripter.

Comment: The position of the NPE would imply that there is no element with the id="ctl00_phContent_ucUnifiedSearch_txtIndvl"

Comment: @Lee you are right. The problem is that htmlunit does not wait for the page to load. I had to use selenium to avoid this kind of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would like to know:
Replacing the line

```
HtmlTextInput textField3 = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("ctl00_phContent_ucUnifiedSearch_txtIndvl");
```

With the following loop:

```
HtmlTextInput textField3 = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("ctl00_phContent_ucUnifiedSearch_txtIndvl");
while(textField3 != null) {
  webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100)
  textField3 = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("ctl00_phContent_ucUnifiedSearch_txtIndvl");
}
```

This loop will wait until HTMLUnit has an element by that ID.